# Find the limit without l'Hopital

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

How to find this limit without L'Hopital

$\lim_{x \to 0}\Bigl(\dfrac{3^x-5^x}{x}\Bigr)$ ??

Answer (score 7):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3^x-5^x}{x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{3^h-3^0}{h}-\frac{5^h-5^0}{h}\right)$$

Use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: If resourcing to derivatives is allowed, why not L'Hospital? It seems too restrictive, though perhaps some teacher may want the students to practice this way

Comment: @DonAntonio Differentiation is taught before introducing L'Hospital's Rule.  I've posted a second answer that doesn't rely at all of derivatives.

Comment: @MarkViola I agree with you, best way when possible to use it.

Comment: @DonAntonio The given limit is essentially equivalent to computing $\lim_{x\to0}(a^x-1)/x$, which is just a derivative. A good teacher should emphasize the fact that $\lim_{x\to0}(e^x-1)/x$ *is* the derivative at zero of the exponential function; likewise for $\lim_{x\to0}(\sin x)/x$.

Comment: Small critique: You don't know the limit exists until you prove it does. Why write $\lim_{x\to 0}$ so early? You certainly don't know you can write the limit, which you don't know exists yet, as the difference of two other limits, which you haven't shown exist yet. I would get rid of the limit signs at the beginning and simply write$$\frac{3^x-5^x}{x} = \frac{3^x-3^0}{x} - \frac{5^x-5^0}{x}.$$Now you're good to go with your explanation.

Comment: @Zhw. Yes, I know.  But the word HINT preceeds the development.  So, I took the liberty of proceeding carelessly.

Comment: OK, good point.

Answer (score 1):

By standard limit (and derivative definition)

$$\frac{a^x-1}{x}\to \log a$$

we have

$$\dfrac{3^x-5^x}{x}=\dfrac{3^x-1}{x}-\dfrac{5^x-1}{x}\to\log 3-\log 5=\log\frac 35$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expansion of $a^x$ to expand $3^x$ and $5^x$. Then proceed further.
Hint $a^x = Exp(xlna)$.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea than in other answer:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3^x - 5^x}{x} = -\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(5/3)^x - 1}{x}3^x = -\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(5/3)^x - 1}{x}\lim_{x\to 0}3^x
$$
and apply the definition of derivative.

Answer (score 0):

I remember back when I took calculus that we were given the definition
$$\ln x=\int_1^x \frac{dt}t$$
And then $\exp(x)=e^x$ was the inverse function to that and we were supposed to prove everything from that. In this case from the laws of logarithms and exponents,
$$\frac{3^x-5^x}x=-3^x\frac{\left(\frac53\right)^x-1}x=-3^x\frac{\exp\left(x\ln\frac53\right)-1}x$$
Then if $y=\exp\left(x\ln\frac53\right)$, then
$$\ln y=x\ln\frac53=\int_1^y\frac{dt}t$$
if $x>0$, then $1/y\le1/t\le1$ over the interval of integration, so
$$1-\frac1y=\frac1y(y-1)\le x\ln\frac53\le y-1$$
So
$$x\ln\frac53+1\le y\le\frac1{1-x\ln\frac53}=\frac{x\ln\frac53}{1-x\ln\frac53}+1$$
So that
$$\ln\frac53\le\frac{y-1}x=\frac{\exp\left(x\ln\frac53\right)-1}x\le\frac{\ln\frac53}{1-x\ln\frac53}$$
So it follows from the squeeze theorem that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\exp\left(x\ln\frac53\right)-1}x=\ln\frac53$$
If $x<0$, then
$$x\ln\frac53=\int_1^y\frac{dt}t=-\int_y^1\frac{dt}t$$
And
$$1-y\le\int_y^1\frac{dt}t=-x\ln\frac53\le\frac1y(1-y)$$
Which works out to
$$\ln\frac53\ge\frac{y-1}x=\frac{\exp\left(x\ln\frac53\right)-1}x\ge\frac{\ln\frac53}{1-x\ln\frac53}$$
So that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}\frac{\exp\left(x\ln\frac53\right)-1}x=\ln\frac53$$
The same approach shows also that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\exp\left(x\ln3\right)=1$$
So
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{3^x-5^x}x=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}-\exp\left(x\ln3\right)\frac{\exp\left(x\ln\frac53\right)-1}x=-(1)\left(\ln\frac53\right)=-\ln\frac53$$